# How to consume WCF after passing C# class object

Tags: c#, asp.net, wpf, wcf

My WCF contains two methods. The first is simple which returns string and takes string as parameter, but in second method I am passing a class containing properties as parameter and return string.

When I comment second method then I am able to get `WCF_Masters.ServiceClient` object in client application but after uncommenting 2nd method I am unable to get that object.

I get only `CompositeType` instead of `ServiceClient` of My WCF service whose name is WCF_Masters.

Note that I am trying to consume WCF in WPF Windows application.

How can I get rid of this issue?

### Edit

My WCF methods are:

```
public String GetMessage(string vName) 
{
   return "Hello world from " + vName; 
} 

public String SaveEmployee(EmployeeMasterSC vEmployeeMasterSC) 
{
    String mReturnMsg = string.Empty;
    EmployeeMasterDAL vEmployeeMasterDAL = null; 
    vEmployeeMasterDAL = new EmployeeMasterDAL(); 
    mReturnMsg = vEmployeeMasterDAL.SaveEmployee(vEmployeeMasterSC);    
     //mEmpDset.EmployeeData = Mdset; return mReturnMsg; 
}
```

Comment: My Both WCF Methods are:

public String GetMessage(string vName)
    {
        return "Hello world from " + vName;
    }


    public String SaveEmployee(EmployeeMasterSC vEmployeeMasterSC)
    {
        String mReturnMsg = string.Empty;

        EmployeeMasterDAL vEmployeeMasterDAL = null;

        vEmployeeMasterDAL = new EmployeeMasterDAL();
        mReturnMsg = vEmployeeMasterDAL.SaveEmployee(vEmployeeMasterSC);
        //mEmpDset.EmployeeData = Mdset;
        return mReturnMsg;
    }

Comment: Can you please provide code?

Comment: How is your EmployeeMasterSC class defined ?

Comment: I have added a class library in client WPF application and with the name "StateClass" and inside that I have added a class called "EmployeeMasterSC.cs" and added that class library dll reference to the WCF application.

Comment: Is there somethime wrong in my approach? If Yes then please suggest some better approach, I am very new in WCF and WPF.

Comment: well we're actually unable to reproduce your issue. Please provide steps to get there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the solution guys, It was the issue of database name I have Written incorrectly "AirportPortal" instead of "DB_AirportPortal" in WCF while inserting records into database

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly, you should not be adding a reference to your WPF DLL in your WCF service. Define the model in your service and then instantiate that model (by reference) in your WPF application, which is consuming the service.

I believe the reason it works when you comment out the 2nd method is that your 1st method has no reference to class structures defined in the WPF DLL.

Comment: I have changed my structure of coding and move the "EmployeeMasterSC" into the WCF application and used in the client application. It worked fine for me but now I am error on WCF while calling SaveEmployee method client application. Error is "A first chance exception of type 'System.ServiceModel.FaultException' occurred in mscorlib.dll"

Comment: Giving Error : "The requested service, 'http://localhost:6000/Service.svc' could not be activated. See the server's diagnostic trace logs for more information."